# For a Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$, what does $\nabla^a \nabla_a$ mean?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, covariance

[image]

Here $\nabla$ is the levi-civita connection of the given metric $g$. I am stuck at the last equality (g). What on earth does $$\nabla^a \nabla_a$$ mean? Isn't it just $$g^{ab}\nabla_a \nabla_b~?$$ But, then the equality does not hold because the left side of (g) is just $$g^{ab}\partial_a\partial_bf$$ and the right side of (g) contains more than that. Could anyone please help me what $\nabla^a \nabla_a$ mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because:-- Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use MathJax instead. See https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/

Comment: OP's last formula $g^{ab}\partial_a\partial_bf$ cannot be the d'Alembertian $\Box f$ since it does not transform as a scalar under general coordinate transformations.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is a scalar, $\nabla_a f=\partial_a f$ is a vector. Applying (e) gives the desired result. Equivalently, $$\nabla^a\nabla_a f=g^{ab}\nabla_a\nabla_b f=g^{ab}\partial_a\nabla_b f-g^{ab}\Gamma_{ab}^c\nabla_c f,$$where the second term is a consequence of the fact that the leftmost $\nabla$ is applied to a vector $\nabla_b f$, not a scalar. Of course, we can rewrite this as $g^{ab}\partial_a\partial_b f-g^{ab}\Gamma_{ab}^c\partial_c f$.

Comment: Vector? Isn't the result of covariant derivative applied to a scalar supposed to be scalar?

Comment: @Keith No! It has a spacetime index.

Comment: In each $\nabla_a f$, the index $a$ is fixed. I thought the output of a covariant derivative should be the same as the input.

Comment: @Keith As an example, $\nabla_0 f$ is a component of a vector; that's not the same thing as a scalar, because it doesn't transform the same way under a coordinate transformation.

Comment: Then is the result of a scalar input of a covariant derivative not a scalar? I become extremely confused...Then what is the output called?

Comment: As far as I know, $\nabla_a f$ is the directional derivative, which I know is a scalar...

Comment: @Keith I'm not sure people have a name for one component of a vector, because it's not worth it. You shouldn't think of any of these equations one value of each index at a time; you should think of them as statements about a full tensor (or something else; sadly, some of these equations deal with non-tensor objects).

Comment: Isn't the directional derivative a scalar? That is my main concern. And isn't the result of a (q,r) tensor of a covariant derivative a (q,r) tensor?

Comment: $f$ is a scalar so $\nabla_a f = \partial_a f$. But, $\nabla_a f$ is a vector so $\nabla_a ( \nabla_b f ) \neq \partial_a ( \nabla_b f)$.

Comment: @Keith You're confusing directional derivatives with covariant ones.

Comment: And I still have trouble showing the equality. How should I proceed?

Comment: @Keith: the directional derivative depends on a direction.  So, given some vector $u^{a}$, the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $\bf u$ is $u^{a}\nabla_{a}f$.  Thus, we can interpret $\nabla_{a}f$ as a one-form $\theta(u)$ waiting for an arbitrary direction $u$ to be input.  But since it is a one-form, it has a tensor index.  Normally, we talk about $\nabla_{a}f$ as being the total differential of $f$ or of $g^{ab}\nabla_{b}f$ as the gradient of $f$